# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'editQuoteModalShown') react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to create the functionality of opening and closing a modal form using react-redux and redux toolkit. It throws me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'editQuoteModalShown')
```

*store.jsx*

```
import { apiSlice } from "./api/apiSlice";
import { editQuoteModalSlice } from "../features/quotes/editQuoteModalSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
    editQuoteModalSlice: editQuoteModalSlice,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
  devTools: true,
});

setupListeners(store.dispatch);
```

*editQuoteModalSlice.jsx*

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  editQuoteModalShown: false,
};

export const editQuoteModalSlice = createSlice({
  name: "editQuoteModalSlice",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setEditQuoteModalShownDispatch: (state, action) => {
      state.editQuoteModalShown = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const editQuoteModalShownSelector = (state) =>
  state.editQuoteModalSlice.editQuoteModalShown;

export const { setEditQuoteModalShownDispatch } =
  editQuoteModalSlice.actions;

export default editQuoteModalSlice.reducer;
```

I am using the selector this way:
*EditQuoteModal.jsx*

```
import {
  editQuoteModalShownSelector,
  setEditQuoteModalShownDispatch,
} from "./editQuoteModalSlice";

export default function EditQuoteModal() {

  const editQuoteModalShown = useSelector(editQuoteModalShownSelector);

  return (
    <div>
      {editQuoteModalShown && (<Modal />)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have imported everything correctly. Don't know what is causing the error.

Comment: I don't see the import for the useSelector, Do you have that imported correctly?

Comment: Yes I imported that correctly. I just didn't paste that here

Comment: in your store replace    editQuoteModalSlice: editQuoteModalSlice, with
    editQuoteModalSlice: editQuoteModalSlice.reducer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The `store` is not importing the correct export from `editQuoteModalSlice`.

store.js

```js
import { editQuoteModalSlice } from "../features/quotes/editQuoteModalSlice";
```

The reducer function is the ***default*** export from `editQuoteModalSlice`, not a named export.

editQuoteModalSlice.js

```js
export default editQuoteModalSlice.reducer;
```

`editQuoteModalSlice` is undefined as an import in `store.js` and passed along  as the reducer when creating the store object.

store.js

```js
import {
  editQuoteModalSlice // <-- undefined
} from "../features/quotes/editQuoteModalSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
    editQuoteModalSlice: editQuoteModalSlice, // <-- undefined reducer
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
  devTools: true,
});
```

## Solution

Import the correct export from the `editQuoteModalSlice` file.

store.js

```js
import editQuoteModalReducer from "../features/quotes/editQuoteModalSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
    editQuoteModalSlice: editQuoteModalReducer, // <-- defined reducer
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
  devTools: true,
});
```